# SSL MaxFragmentLength extension in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I need to define MaxFragmentLength (max packet len) for TLS server written in C#. Is this extension supported and how to enable it (it seems disabled/not supported).

This is max_fragment_length in RFC6066

Comment: Could you provide some of the code that you're using so I can get an idea of what you need?

Comment: It is standard sequence of .Net API-s: ...
TcpClient client = xx.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateClientCertificate)))
{
  sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
  ...
}

Comment: Dang this is a tough problem. I've been working on it, and it's hard to find any info on it.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [`SSLStream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) be what you're looking for?

Comment: sslStream.Length is the length of underlying stream. It is different and cannot be modified (read only). 'max_fragment_length' extension must be supported by the SSL/Web server and eventually there must be a flag to enabled/disable its support or all extensions.